# SharePoint Online List is blank with data

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online list with three entries of data from a different user, however, when I view the same list it's blank. When the user who created the entries views the list, they see the entries.

I have Full Ownership permission on this SharePoint site, while the person entering data has Edit access.

Under List Settings > Advanced Settings, I have the radio buttons set for "Read all items" and "Create and edit all items". Then, under versioning settings, I have require content approval set to No.

Again, I need the list entries to be viewable to everybody who has access to this list. Not just the person who created the entry.

Thanks.

Comment: And you checked if there is a [ME] filter on the View?

Comment: Yes, I did. That too was empty and is a normal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that within the SharePoint List View, I had an incorrect Date value. The List was trying to display content from a date that did not exist.